# The most efficient way to verify an email after a user changes it in Django

Tags: python, django, web, server-side, implementation

I have a token generator function, I know all about how to set up an smtp relay service, I also implemented
My own email verification after signing up for the website but what I'm searching for is an alternative way to verify my users email if they ever changed them from their profile settings, or, should I do it the same way as of setting their user is_active to False and then turn it back to True when they activate from the link I send them.

I have searched YouTube, Google and many other platforms for a way to implement email verification, didn't find many answers on the topic, nor, many discussions actually. So, what is it in your opinion the best way to implement such a feature to a Django website ?

Comment: This is more of an opinion based question, not totally suited for stackoverflow. You'd probably have more luck using message boards like Reddit. They also list a few resources like a community Discord on the Django Github readme. https://github.com/django/django

Comment: have a look at the allauth package workflow

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.